# Publish Wear OS watch face and an Android companion app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, wear-os, google-play-console

I have built a watch face app for Wear OS on Watch Face Studio and published the .aab from there to Google Play. So far so good, however I've now built a companion app with Android Studio and got another .aab from there.
My question is how do I publish both of these separate apps as one to Google Play? (Both have the same package name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publishing them in the same listing with the same package name is completely normal and in fact required.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/packaging

Under Advanced make sure you have a Wear OS type added

[image]

Not sure if it is different when you start with a Wear OS app only.

Comment: I was having a problem as I had the same versionCode in both, the solution is to have a distinct version code in each .aab and publish both in the same release. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For clear understanding, make two builds one for watch and one for mobile app, with different version names, and select both builds and drag and drop both on upload console, and rollout together.

Comment: I tried to do that but the console keeps saying that the version code was already used.